# Uninstalling user install of Apache on Mac Mini

Tags: apache, macos

I got a MacMini at work for development, and was asked to follow this article to install SVN on it: http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html  The article assumes that only Apache 1.3 was installed and asks the reader to install Apache 2.  I've since learned that the MacMini has Apache 2 already installed.  So basically I've installed two versions of Apache 2.  The preinstalled one has access to PHP, so I wanted to remove my version, but I'm unsure of how.

My version has httpd.conf stored at:
/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
And the preinstalled version has it stored at:
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf, which I believe is an alias for /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the Apache2 folder from the location you specified, /Library/StartupItems/Apache2, and /Library/Receipts/Apache2.pkg according to:

http://www.glinder.com/bulkfiles/UNIXInfo/Apache2_Install_Guide.pdf